# Use styles in my HierarchicalDataTemplate to properly format my MenuItem(s) bindings

Tags: wpf, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a hierarchical set of data that I am binding to a menu, and it works fine but I am displaying the menu items icon and name in a stackpanel which are both in the header section of the menu, this results in a odd look as the icon column of the bound menuitems does not get used. Would like to know how to go about properly formatting my XAML so the icon of the various bound types actually gets bound to the MenuItem's Icon property rather than sitting in the Header section.

[image]

```
    <Menu x:Name="menu" >
        <Menu.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ODIF:PluginContainer}">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                    <MultiBinding>
                        <MultiBinding.Converter>
                            <local:CompositeDeviceCollectionConverter />
                        </MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <Binding/>
                        <Binding Path="Instance.Devices"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding PluginIcon}" Width="16" Height="16">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PluginIcon}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PluginName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ODIF:OutputDevice}" ItemsSource="{Binding InputChannels}">
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding StatusIcon}" Width="16" Height="16">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusIcon}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeviceName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ODIF:InputDevice}" ItemsSource="{Binding OutputChannels}">
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding StatusIcon}" Width="16" Height="16">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusIcon}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeviceName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ODIF:DeviceChannel}">
                <local:ChannelBox Channel="{Binding}" Width="200" Click="ChannelClicked"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </Menu.Resources>
        <MenuItem x:Name="menuItem" BorderThickness="0" 
                  Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=menu, Mode=OneWay}" 
                  Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=menu, Mode=OneWay}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Plugins, ElementName=InputChannelBoxMenuControl}" Padding="0">
            <MenuItem.Header>
                <local:ChannelBox x:Name="SelectedChannelBox" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=menuItem, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=menuItem, Mode=OneWay}" Channel="{Binding SelectedChannel, ElementName=InputChannelBoxMenuControl}"/>
            </MenuItem.Header>
        </MenuItem>

    </Menu>
```

UPDATE:

Editing the `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle` provides me with the odd behavior where the last menu item in a hierarchy contains the root items icon:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to achieve this based on another user's answer that has since been deleted that only needed a little more modification to work with the varying types I use in my binding.

This feels very "hackish" so if somebody thinks of something better I hope they will post, but until then i've learned that sometimes you have to trick and or strongarm WPF into doing what you want and hope it doesn't break down the road;

Adding this to my root menu item achieved the results I was looking for:

```
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <local:IsNullConverter x:Key="isNullConverter"/>
                        <Image x:Key="IconImage" x:Shared="False">
                            <Image.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PluginIcon, Converter={StaticResource isNullConverter}}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding PluginIcon}" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusIcon, Converter={StaticResource isNullConverter}}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding StatusIcon}" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Image.Style>
                        </Image>
                    </Style.Resources>
                    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource IconImage}" />
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And the converter:

```
public class IsNullConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value == null);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("IsNullConverter can only be used OneWay.");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: A better more "break-proof" way of doing this may be to implement a typeOf IvalueConverter and check against that instead of just blindly checking if properties exist.